# How to implement local push notification to looks similar to native alarm app?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to implement an iOS app, which has very similar functionality to native alarm app. I want to implement this screen so it appears on the lock screen:

[image]

Is it possible to implement this functionality with my own app?

Comment: How about checking [link](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/extensions/widgets/)?

Comment: Widgets appear above the quick action list when you apply pressure to an app icon on the Home screen using 3D Touch.

Comment: I want to have local notification, which appear on the lock screen...